# Character Countdown

Tags: python-3.x, string, countdown

I'm trying to create a function. Function; it will simply be designed to increase the last letter sequence from its position in the alphabet or letter list.

```
import time
def CountDown(text,reply=3):
    abc = list("ABCDEFGHIJ")
    c = 1
    text_list = list(text)
    while 1:
        Index = abc.index(text_list[-c])
        if not list(filter(lambda a: a!=abc[-1], text_list)):
            return "".join(text_list)
        if text_list[-c] == abc[-1]:
            text_list[-c] = abc[0]
            c += 1
            continue
        else:
            s=1
            while 1:
                text_list[-c] = abc[(Index+s) if (Index+s)<len(abc) else 0]
                if text_list.count(abc[(Index+s) if (Index+s)<len(abc) else 0])+1<reply:        
                    break
                s+=1
            text_list[-c] = abc[(Index+s) if (Index+s)<len(abc) else 0]   
            return "".join(text_list)    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    code="ABHD"
    while 1:
        code=CountDown(code)
        time.sleep(0.5)        
        print(code)
```

OUTPUT:

```
ABHE
ABHF
ABHG
ABHI
ABHJ
ABIA
ABIC
ABID
ABIE
ABIF
ABIG
ABIH
ABIJ
ABJA
ABJC
ABJD
ABJE
ABJF
ABJG
ABJH
ABJI

....(idling)
```

The code doesn't give an output after a while. I think there is something wrong.

How can I fix this code sample?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include additional examples of input and expected output of the function (as is, if it was working as intended).

Comment: I edited it. @HampusLarsson